# How can I replace Google Place autocomplete "not found" picture in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to replace this picture only
[image]

How to to this? Does anybody know? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your **vector** icon to `drawable` directory. The name of the icon should be `quantum_ic_cloud_off_vd_theme_24.xml`.

This is the result:
[image]